Converting character vectors to the same units of measure
Problem: I have a character vector that is a mix of foot/inchs, m and cm. I am trying to convert them all to cm.
Vector looks something like this:
Height <- c("165", "185", "5'1", "1.88")

Converting the "5'1" was easy (found this piece of code on stackoverlow):
 ft_cm <- function (str_ft_inch) {
   elem <- as.integer(unlist(strsplit(str_ft_inch, "'")))
   inch <- elem[1] * 12 + elem[2]
   return(conv_unit(inch, "inch", "cm")) }

Height_converted <- sapply(Height, ft_cm) 
> 165 185  5'1   1.88
  NA  NA  154.94 NA

Now I want to replicate this for the metre "1.88". I have recycled the ft_cm function. This is the new function:
m_cm <- function (str_m_cm) {
   elem <- as.integer(unlist(strsplit(str_m_cm, ".")))
   cm <- elem[1] * 100 + elem[2]
return(cm)
}

Height_m_to_cm <- sapply(Height, m_cm)
> 165 185 5'1 1.88
  NA  NA  NA  NA

I want my desired outcome to be:
Height_converted
> 165 185 5'1    1.88
  165 185 154.94 188

I'm not sure why it is having trouble with this. Any help would be appreciated.
P.S. This was only a snippet of a much longer character vector.

In the case of meter to cm you don't need strsplit, just coerce to numeric and multiply by 100. (Use as.numeric, not as.integer)

I agree with Rui Barradas that string splitting the metric values is not a good solution. To clarify why it failed, the character . is being interpreted as a regular expression meaning "any character". If you did want to split on the literal . character, you would have to use strsplit(str_m_cm, "\\.")

I think you can just sub the . away (assuming you always have two digits after the decimal point as shown), then grepl for feet, and convert these.
> cnv_unts <- \(x) {
+   x <- sub('\\.', '', x)
+   ft <- grepl('\'', x)
+   x[ft] <- strsplit(x[ft], '\'') |> lapply(type.convert, as.is=TRUE) |>
+     sapply(\(.) sum(.*c(12, 1))*2.54)
+   as.numeric(x)
+ }
> cnv_unts(Height)
[1] 165.00 185.00 154.94 154.94 188.00


Data:
Height <- c("165", "185", "5'1", "5'1", "1.88")

